# How to prove that a matrix inverse is invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

First off, I'm trying to prove that $(A^{-1})^{-1} = A$, but in my proof, I assume that $A^{-1}$ is invertible. I'd like to see or do a proof that $A^{-1}$ must be non-singular, but I'm stuck at square one.

Comment: This follows from general considerations: a function is invertible iff it is 1-1 and surjective. From this follows *at once* that its inverse is *also* 1-1 and surjective and, thus, also invertible itself.

Comment: Showing that $A$ is the inverse of $A^{-1}$ shows that $A^{-1}$ is invertible

Answer (score 4):

By definition a matrix A is the inverse of another matrix B if $AB = BA = Id$. It is clear from the equation above that if $A$ is the inverse of $B$ then $B$ is the inverse of $A$.

Comment: Ah, thanks! That also, in one fell swoop, explains that B is invertible at all. Allow me to feel like an idiot for a while.